# Can load wire have power?

Tags: gfci

I’m replacing a GFCI in my kitchen. I pulled out the old one without labeling the line and load wires. I flipped the appropriate breaker (I think) but still have power to one of the hot wires. Could I be getting a current back through the load wire?

Comment: It could be that you did not flip the correct breaker. If you flip that breaker back on, does it power one of the black wires that is unpowered with it off? How many black wires did you have in the box? How many cables? (Each "Romex" NM cable will usually have one black, one white, one bare in one sheath.)

Comment: please do not post a question until you are 100% certain that you flipped the correct breaker or if none of the breakers cut the power ....... the question is bogus otherwise

Comment: Thanks Jim I ended up going back to the beginning and found the 2 leads by experimenting then adding the 2 loads that connected to the 2nd GFCI and repeated the process. My first GFCI shared a box with my garbage disposal switch so the box was full of wires which in turn fed the 2nd box which shared a over the sink light with another GFCI that feeds other outlets down the line. Have A Blessed Weekend

Answer (score 0):

Standard rule for a GFCI is

Part 1, hook up the `LINE` terminals only, then stop.  Do a test of the GFCI, run it through its paces and make sure it is fully operational.   If it won't behave normally, you hooked it up wrong, back up and iterate on that.

Part 2. Then, power off again and hook up the `LOAD` terminals.  If that doesn't work (typically it trips), then back up and iterate on that, but you only have to back up to your successful checkpoint in part 1.

Where people get in trouble, especially newbies, is when they try to do both steps at once.   Don't bother, ther are no brownie points for that.